# Burninate the "unused" tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[unused](/questions/tagged/unused) is used on 62 questions, but it is not useful at all: It is used in completely different contexts, and in none of them is the tag relevant.

For example, it is used in:

- [Xcode WARNING: Unused Entity Issue: Unused Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477266/xcode-warning-unused-entity-issue-unused-variable)
- [Impacts of having unused JAR files in CLASSPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980483/impacts-of-having-unused-jar-files-in-classpath)
- [How to find and remove all unused resources in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098633/how-to-find-and-remove-all-unused-resources-in-visual-studio-2010)
- [Removing unused variables from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051710/removing-unused-variables-from-jquery)

In some questions, the tag really means [unused](/questions/tagged/unused)[variables](/questions/tagged/variables), [unused](/questions/tagged/unused)[resources](/questions/tagged/resources), [unused](/questions/tagged/unused)[result](/questions/tagged/result), [unused](/questions/tagged/unused)[file](/questions/tagged/file), or [unused](/questions/tagged/unused)[methods](/questions/tagged/methods), where both the tags are used from the question.

[unused](/questions/tagged/unused) should be burninated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]